# Manually Validating Symfony Form with JsFormValidatorBundle

Tags: jquery, validation, symfony

I'm having a little issue with the Symfony JsFormValidatorBundle

https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle

I want to have 2 options

1)  Validate and submit the form manually (e.g. don't rely on submit)
or
2)  Validate and do something else (to be specific make a ajax request with the form data).

However I can't seem to work out how to do this wuth the JsFormValidatorBundle plugin.

According to the docs.

> 3.10 Form submit by Javasrcipt
>
> If you want to submit your form by click on link or by another Javascript action:

```
$('a#link_submit').click(function(){
    $('form#user').jsFormValidator('submitForm');
});
```

Trying this - it does NOT submit the form (when of course specifying the correct form).

So even if I got above to work I would also like to find a way to extend the bundle so I can validate but not submit? any ideas?

Comment: Add the form-type and the template part that renders the form to the question please.

Comment: Hi Nifr, not sure what you mean when you say form-type?

Comment: I meant the class containing the form you're rendering (if any) and please add the php/twig-template that you use for rendering the form.

Comment: After updating to the latest version, I get a little further.  The forms class name is fpjvalitable now I do.
   
     $('.form_submit').click(function(e){
        $('.fpjvalitable').jsFormValidator('submitForm');
        if($('.error_exists').length == 0) {
            $('.fpjvalitable').trigger('submit');
        }
    });
The submitForm part "Validates" the form now but doesn't submit it - but I then can trigger manually... a hack but it works :(

Comment: Nice to hear you're making progress. sadly until now nobody can really reproduce your situation due to the lacking form in the question - otherwise you might have an answer yet. Edit the question -> Show us the code :)

Comment: Guys if you are still alive please help with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439917/symfony-jsformvalidatorbundle-run-validation-on-custom-event